# Prove that either $f(x) = ax + b$ for all $x \in [0,1]$ for some constants $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ or $t \in (0,1)$ such that $|f(1) - f(0)| < |f'(t)|$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f \colon [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function which is differentiable on $(0,1)$. Prove that either $f(x) = ax + b$ for all $x \in [0,1]$ for some constants $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ or there exists $t \in (0,1)$ such that $|f(1) - f(0)| < |f'(t)|$.

---

I have found a solution of this problem [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h3071898p27731891):

> If $f(0)=f(1)$, we are done by Rolle's Theorem, hence assume $f(0)\neq f(1)$ and consider $g(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{f(1)-f(0)}$, which is continuous, differentiable and satisfies $g(0)=0$, $g(1)=1$ and $g'(x)=\frac{f'(x)}{f(1)-f(0)}$. Therefore we may assume $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$, and we wish to prove that there exists $t\in (0,1)$ such that $|f'(t)|>1$. If $f(t)>t$ or $f(t)<t$ for some $t\in (0,1)$, we are done by MVT on $(0,t)$ or $(t,1)$, respectively. Else $f(x)=x$ for all $x\in (0,1)$, so $f$ is linear.

---

1. Here they took the function $g(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{f(1)-f(0)}$ into consideration. What might have been the motivation behind it?
2. How did they assume $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$?

Comment: I think it is just a trick. You can assume it, because if you prove the result for $g$ you would have the result for $f$. So, I does not matter if you assume it or not. If you don't have those equalities, than you prove the result for $g$ and then you have for $f$.

Comment: @YgorArthur are you talking about 2?

Comment: both haha First "I think it is just a trick" was for 1.

Answer (score 1):

The idea, with both of your questions, is to reduce the general case for $f$ (where we assume $f$ is continuous on $[0, 1]$ and differentiable on $(0, 1)$) to a more specific case (where we assume all of the above *and* $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$).

The first part of the proof is about taking a general $f$ satisfying these conditions, and constructing a $g$ that also satisfies the conditions, as well as $g(0) = 0$ and $g(1) = 1$. Moreover, we want it to be clear that, if the conclusion holds for $g$, then the conclusion holds for $f$. So, if we can prove the specific case (i.e. where $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$), then we can apply it to $g$, and that should make the result hold for $f$.

What's a little lacking from this proof is the crucial step where the property holding for $g$ implies the property holds for $f$. So, let's assume the second part of the proof holds true, and we now know that $g(x) = ax + b$ for some $a, b$ (indeed, the proof says $g(x) = x$ specifically) or some $t \in [0, 1]$ exists such that $|g'(t)| > |g(1) - g(0)| = 1$. If it's the former, then
$$f(x) = (f(1) - f(0))g(t) + f(0) = (f(1) - f(0))x + f(0),$$
i.e. of the form $ax + b$, as required. Otherwise, assuming the latter, then using the same $t$,
$$|f'(t)| = |f(1) - f(0)| \cdot \left|\frac{f'(t)}{f(1) - f(0)}\right| = |f(1) - f(0)| \cdot |g'(t)| > |f(1) - f(0)|,$$
since $f(1) - f(0) \neq 0$. Thus, if the property holds for $g$, it holds for $f$. So, proving the result for functions like $g$, that are continuous on $[0, 1]$ and differentiable on $(0, 1)$, but also have $g(0) = 0$ and $g(1) = 1$, will prove the same result for the more general functions.

Hopefully this answers your second question: we might as well make the new assumption that $f(0) = 0$ and $g(1) = 1$, because proving for this special case is actually a proof for the general case.

As for your first question, the function $g(x) = \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{f(1) - f(0)}$ is the result of normalising the graph of $f$ so that it begins at $(0, 0)$ and ends at $(1, 1)$ (so if the function is a line, it would have to be $x$, as used in the proof). If we first subtract $f(0)$ from $f(x)$, i.e. let $h(x) = f(x) - f(0)$, this produces the same graph as $f$, but shifted vertically so that it begins at $(0, 0)$ - note that $h(0) = f(0) - f(0) = 0$.

Then dividing by letting $g(x) = \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{f(1) - f(0)} = \frac{h(x)}{h(1)}$, we are then taking the graph of $h$, and scaling it vertically so that $g(1) = 1$ (while still having $g(0) = h(0)/h(1) = 0$).

Note that neither adding a constant or scaling vertically will affect the result. Adding a constant will be eliminated from differentiation, will be cancelled when taking $f(1) - f(0)$, and won't interfere with the $ax + b$ form (it will just change the constant $b$). Scaling vertically will introduce a scalar that will cancel from both sides of $|f'(t)| > |f(1) - f(0)|$, and will simply modify the $a$ in $ax + b$. Since both of these operations are "free" for us to do, in a sense, we might as well use them to make the problem more simple.